# OKHttp response fail: java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I request to link for getting JSON but response.body().string() value always have an error. Another way, I split response.body().string() to response.body() and string but Android studio don't find ResponseBody. 2 way doesn't work. Please help!

```
String doGetRequest(String url) throws IOException {
       Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
        System.out.println(response.body().string());
        //ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
        //String content = responseBody.string();
        //System.out.println(content);
        return response.body().string();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 31):

> response.body().string() → You can only call string() once.

Because response body can be huge so OkHttp doesn’t store it in memory, it reads it as a stream from the network when you need it.

When you read the body as a string() OkHttp downloads response body and returns it to you without keeping the reference to the string, it can’t be downloaded twice without new request.

You are calling it more than once.

```
try(..){
    System.out.println(response.body().string());// once
    return response.body().string();`// twice
 }
```

You can save response in variable by calling it once then use that variable for further usage.

```
try(..){
  String responseData = response.body().string();//Be cautious about memory constraint here.
  System.out.println(responseData);
  return responseData;`
}
```

Comment: yeah, I saw in debug mode but I used Responsebody and then cast to string. Same error occurs again. I found a new way to solved it. I closed response such as `response.close();` It solved my problem.

Comment: Even when you call it from the debugger before your code runs `.string()` ‍♂️

Answer (score 12):

This happens because `.string()` can be called only once

You can solve the issue in the following way (Java):

```
ResponseBody responseBodyCopy = response.peekBody(Long.MAX_VALUE);
responseBodyCopy.string();
```

By copying the response body you avoid using `.string()` twice

Answer (score 1):

maybe you are closing your response in an interceptor like this

```
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
//...
val response = chain.proceed(builder.build())
response.close()
//...
}
```